# Trying to use Java Swing and Filechooser but there is an error in my code

Tags: java, swing, cmd, filechooser

I have a java program with a GUI as follows. What it does is it consists of a button that allows a user to select a file and on selecting the file the command prompt should open up and change to the directory of that file.

However the command prompt doesn't open up with this code. How do I modify the code so I change to the directory of the selected file?

```java
public class GUIProject {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f=new JFrame();
        //final JTextField tf=new JTextField();
        JTextArea File1= new JTextArea("Select the program to test.");
        JTextArea File2= new JTextArea();
        File1.setBounds(50,50, 150,20);
        JButton b=new JButton("Select");
        b.setBounds(50,100,95,30);
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                try {
                    File1();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        f.add(b);
        f.add(File1);
        f.add(File2);
        f.setSize(400,400);
        f.setLayout(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void File1() throws IOException{
        JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser(FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getHomeDirectory());
        int returnValue = jfc.showOpenDialog(null);
        if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File selectedFile = jfc.getSelectedFile();

            ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
                    "cmd.exe", "/c", "cd \"selectedFile.getAbsolutePath()\" && dir");
            builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
            Process p = builder.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Update -

```
    public static void File2() throws IOException{
            JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser(FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getHomeDirectory());

            int returnValue = jfc.showOpenDialog(null);
            

            if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File selectedFile = jfc.getSelectedFile();
                
        
                System.out.println(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath()); 
                String[] commands = {"cd selectedFile.getAbsolutePath()", "mvn clean test -DskipTests -Dmaven.compiler.source=1.8 -Dmaven.compiler.target=1.8 -B -f C:\\Users\\A\\Documents\\GitHub\\ThisNew\\flacoco\\examples\\exampleFL1\\FLtest1", "java -jar target/flacoco-1.0.6-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar --projectpath examples\\exampleFL1\\FLtest1 --output finalresult.csv --format CSV"};
                String command = "cmd.exe /c " + String.join(" && ", commands);
                ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command.split(" "));
                pb.inheritIO(); //to see the result in the console
                pb.start();
            
    
        
              }
        
        }
```

Comment: You might want to build your change directory command string first and print it to the console so you can verify it before you use the `ProcessBuilder`.  You also should have run dozens of tests before you even started to code your `ActionListener`.  Write a little, test a lot.

Comment: .. and __never-ever__ do any manual sizing/locating of components, instead use a suitable layoutManager

Comment: According to the code in your question, it looks like you just want to get a listing of all the files in the directory that the user chooses via [JFileChooser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html). I'm guessing that's not really what you want to do. This really seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Firstly, you don't need to change directory via `cd`, just call method [directory](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#directory(java.io.File))

Comment: If you want to execute several commands, why not write a [batch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file) file? What kind of file is the user expected to choose (via `JFileChooser`)? What do you want to do with the file that the user chooses?

Comment: @Abra I want to change to the directory of the file the user has selected.

Comment: _I want to change to the directory of the file the user has selected_ For what purpose? And you also didn't answer my other questions. What kind of file is the user supposed to choose? Should he choose an XML file? And what do you want to do with the file that he chooses?

Answer (score 1):

With this code i wrote below, you can open cmd and set it on desired directory.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class main {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        try{
            String command = "ping www.google.com";
            //remove "\"start;" to hide cmd
            String[] cmd       = new String[]{ "cmd.exe", "/C", "\"start;" + command + "\"" };
            File     directory = new File( "C:/Users" );

            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder( cmd );
            pb.directory( directory );

            Process process = pb.start();

        }catch( IOException e ){
            System.out.println( "Something has gone wrong" );
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if it was helpfull.

Comment: Helpful thanks, but I don't want the user to see the terminal and I want to execute more commands. How could I do that? Thanks.

Comment: @abc I update my code, check it and let me know.

Comment: Hi, I want to do this command String command = "cd \"selectedFile.getAbsolutePath()\"";  but it doesn't seem to work. I want to change directory to the file the user has selected. I added the code you provided and tried but it says the system cannot find the path specified when I try it this way but your part of the code works fine with ping google.

Comment: @abc Yes, you can do this by putting the value of `selectedFile.getAbsolutePath()` inside `pb.directory()`, remember that `.directory()` take a **File** object, and therefore I suggest you to assign the value of `selectedFile.getAbsolutePath()` if it's return value is a string to variable called "directory", like this: `File directory = new File( selectedFile.getAbsolutePath() );`

Comment: I receive ---- Something has gone wrong
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cmd.exe" (in directory "C:\Users\A\Desktop\MUJAVA\selenium-server-4.0.0-alpha-6.jar"): CreateProcess error=267, The directory name is invalid

Comment: @abc this is because you are not pointing to a directory but to a file .jar. You must delete the last part and leave only the folder that contains the file, that is "MUJAVA"

Comment: but JFileChooser won't let me do that, it doesn't do anything until I select a file.

Comment: you can use this: `new File( "YOUR_PATH" ).getParent();`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246320/discussion-between-abc-and-thesmith1222).

Comment: String command = "mvn clean test -DskipTests -Dmaven.compiler.source=1.8 -Dmaven.compiler.target=1.8 -B -f directory"; doesn't give me the selected path but gives me the word directory instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run multible commands you can put them together with `&&` like this:

`cd "C:/users/" && echo hello world && echo I will be executed after`.

The output of this would be:

```
hello world
I will be executed after

C:\Users>
```

In Java this could look like:

```
String[] commands = {"cd C:/users/", "echo Hello world", "echo I will be executed after"};
String command = "cmd.exe /c " + String.join(" && ", commands);
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command.split(" "));
pb.inheritIO(); //to see the result in the console
pb.start();
```

Comment: @abc I added the Java code. This should now work with your case. If not please provide the commands you want to execute.

Comment: Hi. It still showed me an error and said system can't find the path specified. I have updated my question and added what I tried it at the bottom.

Comment: @abc you are running `cd selectedFile.getAbsolutePath()` in cmd. If you just  copy this line to cmd you will get the error. I beleve you want to change directory to the selected file. Therefor you have to call the method (and not include it into the string) as shown here: `"cd " + selectedFile.getAbsolutePath()`.

Comment: @abc Note also that you can't change directory to a file (that is not a directory). For example you cant run `cd myDirectory/test.txt`. If your `selectedFile` is not a directory you want to get the parent directory by using `selectedFile.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath()` instead.

Comment: Or just simply use `jfc.getCurrentDirectory()`.

Answer (score 0):

A process builder is not supposed to open a new window. It does this in the background by default. You can trick it to open a cmd window with using the parameter `/c start`. Add aother parameter to set the location of the new window: `cmd /c start /D "C:/users/"`.

With a process builder this can look like this:

```
String command = "cmd /c start /D \"C:/users/\"";
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command.split(" "));
pb.start();
```

Comment: okay, suppose I didn't want to see the command terminal but execute more commands after  cd? How could I do that?

Comment: I postet another answer since the question seems to have changed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72911726/13148560